# Android:imageview visibility and remove space between imageviews

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

Hi I am facing problem with the following scenarios

1) I have a common header with icons for all the screens..in one of the screen I have a list view ..when I click on the list it fires an intent ,it is a login screen and when i enter the password an icon should appear on the header...what i did is initially i made the icon invisible in layout and below is my `login` code..

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1); 

           btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
 if(password.equals("1234")){
                        lblResult.setText("password successful.");
                        imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                    } else {
                        lblResult.setText("wrong password");}

                    finish();}
```

but its not working..where I am wrong..

2) I have 4 images on header..and i set visibility on and off on middle icon ..when icon is invisible i want the remaining icons side by side ..but now i am getting a blank space between the icons how can i remove that space.
Any suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
now i am getting a blank space between the icons how can i remove that space.
```

[View.GONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

[View.INVISIBLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE) This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.